# What is the proper way to wrap a JSON object in another object?

Tags: c#, json

I have run into this problem before, where I create a data model that will later be serialized into a JSON string, but I want the class containing the properties to also be serialized. See the example below:

I have my data model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prop1")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prop2")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Which would then serialize to:

```
{
    "Prop1":"Some Value",
    "Prop2":"Some Value"
}
```

Is there a way I can make it serialize to:

```
{
    "MyModel":
    {
        "Prop1":"Some Value",
        "Prop2":"Some Value"
    }
}
```

What I am currently doing which does not seem proper at all is something like this to create a wrapping object for my JSON:

`string object = @"{""ticket"":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model) + @"}"`

Is there some kind of attribute I can add to my class something like:

```
[SerializeThisClass, ProperName="MyModel"]
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prop1")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prop2")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { MyModel = model } );
This creates an anonymous object with a simple property named MyModel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new{ MyModel = model})
```

should be ok

Answer (score 2):

Add another class that has MyModel as its member then serialize the parent.

```
public class Parent
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MyModel")]
    public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may achieve that with this

```
 public class MyModel
 {
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prop1")]
      public string Property1 { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prop2")]
      public string Property2 { get; set; }
 }
 public class Wrapper{
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "MyModel")]
    public MyModel myModel{get;set;}
 }
```

then serialize the Wrapper object